# Ajax not call ,console get error Reference Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am getting error when click radio button. Ajax not calling.
ERROR : `ReferenceError: u8neFUbKMQYR2lZa6Ydrku95gknUATeMF067DBd5 is not defined`
My code is here

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('click change', function(e) {
    var target=this.value;
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : '{{ URL::route('generate_method') }}',
        data  : {'choice':target,'_token':{{csrf_token()}}},
        error : function(response){
            alert('SOMETHING WENT WRONG,TRY AGAIN');
        },
        success : function(response){
            $('#place_order_getway').html( );
            $('#place_order_getway').html(response);
        }
    });


});
```

Comment: You left out the important part .... what is the error?

Comment: no idea where that variable comes from, console should tell you what line it is from also